# jQuery Stop Only Animations Being Set

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-transitions, jquery-transit

Say I have this.

```
var e = $('#div');
```

I want to do

```
e.fadeOut(3000).animate({'top':500}, 3000);
```

And then

```
e.animate({'top':250}, 3000);
```

Immediately, stopping the original `top` animation on `e`, but without stopping the fade.

**Note** I am also using the jQuery Transit plugin in place of jQuery animate.

Comment: Are you animating DOM using jQuery and CSS transitions? You wanted to stop any of those animation before new animation begin?

Comment: Yes, so say if there's currently a fade out and an animation on the top running currently, and then the top is set to animate somewhere else; I would want the original top animation to stop, while the fade out keeps happening

Comment: @BrianLeishman Is requirement a) start `e.fadeOut(3000)` -> b) _during_ `.fadeOut` - within `3000` `duration` - `.animate` to `top` : `500` -> c) `.animate` to `top`:`250` - all during initial `.fadeOut` ? Or, should the entire process be total duration of `3000` + `3000` + `3000` - `9000` ?

Comment: Yes, it should be like the first scenario, where the second `top` animation "cuts off" the first one, but leaves the `fadeOut` to finish what it's doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the fade animation with the queue option false. The first button starts both animations and the second button overrides just the top animation.

I think there is another way of doing it using a named queue but I find it more lengthy because you have to manually start the animation with .dequeue('queueName')

```js
$(function(){
 var $div = $('#myDiv');
 var $btnStart = $('#btnStart');
 var $btnEnd = $('#btnEnd');


 $btnStart.click(function(){
  $div.animate({'top':'500px'}, 3000);
  $div.animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 5000, queue: false});
 });
 $btnEnd.click(function(){
  $div.animate({'top':0}, {duration: 3000, queue: false});
 });
});
```

```css
#myDiv{
 background:red;
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnStart">Start</button>
<button id="btnEnd">End</button>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Just noticed you mentioned not wanting to use queue:false. Below it's the same thing using queue names and stopping individual animations.

```js
$(function(){
 var $div = $('#myDiv');
 var $btnStart = $('#btnStart');
 var $btnEnd = $('#btnEnd');

 $btnStart.click(function(){
  $div.animate({'top':'500px'}, {duration: 3000, queue:'top'});
  $div.dequeue('top');
  $div.fadeOut(5000);
 });
 $btnEnd.click(function(){
  $div.stop('top').animate({'top':0}, {duration: 3000, queue: 'top'});
  $div.dequeue('top');
 });
});
```

```css
#myDiv{
 background:red;
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnStart">Start</button>
<button id="btnEnd">End</button>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally, someone has a solution for stopping only _certain_ animations. I've tested this a bit and it appears to be working as expected, but I'll test more tomorrow morning and award the bounty as such when I can confirm everything's working.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var e = $("#div");

$("button").on("click", function() {
  if (!e.is(":animated")) {
      e.animate({"top":"+=500", "opacity":0}, 3000, "linear")
  }
  else {
      e.stop(true, false).animate({"top": "-=250", "opacity":0}, 3000, "linear")
  };  
});
```

```css
#div {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  font-size:36px;
  border:2px solid green;
  background:orange;
  height:54px;
  width:54px;
  text-align:center;
}

button {
  width:54px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>click</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```